# Why file gets corrupted on client side in java socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a java code which sends a `.exe` file from the server to the client using `FileInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`, but the file gets corrupted at the client side.

What could be the reason?

```
command1= ServerFrame.msg1+".exe";
File p=new File(command1);
FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(p);
BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(f);
Integer d=bis.available();
int d1=d;
byte b[]=new byte[d];
bis.read(b,0,d1);
System.out.println(d1);
dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF(d.toString());             // sending length in long
bos.write(b,0,d1);                      // sending the bytess

bos.flush();
bis.close();  
bos.close();
dos.close();
```

Comment: simples, look at `dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());` using the dos a and bos from the same outputsteam but even more you ain't write the content of the file, first writing some length then the content. Side note: if you are to read the entire file, skip all BuffeXXXStream, they are useless (same w/ the output). Also `bis.available()` returns `int`, no need for abomination like Integer.

Comment: Corrupted in what way?  (The answer to that frequently gives direct indication where to look)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `s` is your socket. There are few thing that can be wong in your code:

- `bis.available()` returns the number of bytes that can be read without bocking, not the total size of the file, you should use a loop to read the file
- you use the output stream in two different buffers and you write to both of them without flushing; also, why are you writing UTF?

Here is what you intend to do:

```
private void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[0x1000];
    int r;
    while ((r = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(b, 0, r);
    }
}
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
copy(in, out);
in.close();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

bis.available() returns the bytes available for read, it may not be the full content size, u have to read in a loop till it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone stuck with same problem, buffer size is the culprit in this case :

```
Integer d=bis.available(); 
byte b[]=new byte[d];
```

It should be lesser try 1024 or something:

```
byte b[]=new byte[1024];
```

hope this helps..